# Line break within Paragraph in Vaadin23

Tags: vaadin, line-breaks, paragraph

I need to place an Article object on my page, that I am creating with Vaadin 23.
The article will contain several paragraphs, each one need to be in 3-4 lines of text.
I have:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(p11);
p1.add(p12);
p1.add(p13);
Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(p21);
p2.add(p22)
...
Article article = new Article(p1, p2, ...);
```

where pNN are Java String instances. I want each of these string to be placed on separate line, but do not want to make them individual paragraphs.
Unfortunately, there is no <br> in Vaadin HTML elements.
I tried to add '\n' at the end of strings or <br>, but it doesn't work. No line breaks.
Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add those `\n` characters, and then set this CSS property on the paragraph element.

```java
p1.getStyle().set("white-space", "pre-line");
```